# Ambiguous function call in a complicated inheritance situation

Tags: c++, inheritance, ambiguous

I have the following code :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename I>
class A {
  public:
    void f (I* i) {
      lis.push_back(i);
    }
    vector <I*> lis;
};

class B {
  public:
    int b;
};

class C {
  public:
    double c;
};

class D : public A<B>,
          public A<C> {
  public:
    void g () {
      cout<<"g\n";
    }
};

class E : public B, public C {
  public:
    float e;
};

int main() {
  E* e;
  D d;
  B* b = (B*) e;
  d.f (b);
}
```

This gives me an error saying :-

```
ambig.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ambig.cpp:42:5: error: request for member ‘f’ is ambiguous
ambig.cpp:9:10: error: candidates are: void A<I>::f(I*) [with I = C]
ambig.cpp:9:10: error:                 void A<I>::f(I*) [with I = B]
```

Any idea on how I can work around this?

Comment: I think if `b` were actually a `B*` and not a casted `E*`, the ambiguity would disappear. You probably have a (good?) reason for needing the `E` class, though.

Comment: FYI, you can provoke this issue with a simpler test-case; see http://ideone.com/xBfd4.

Comment: @jpm Yes, there is a good reason for needing E. Basically, B & C are interfaces.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Indeed, that is much simpler. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Maybe if you would describe the situation better, we would be able to help you better.

Comment: @Jari Well it's fairly simple. When I call d.f ((B*) e) then A<B>::f should be called. When I call d.f ((C*) e) then A<C>::f should be called.

Comment: I think in D you can do `using A<B>::f; using A<C>::f;` to bring both candidates into the same class so overload resolution can do its thing. But I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class D : public A<B>,
          public A<C> {
  public:
    using A<B>::f;  // <=== use
    using A<C>::f;  // <=== this
```

It is detailed in the standard using long-winded language, but the simple rule is: all member function overloads must come from the same class.